# Probability for many coin flips

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

Suppose a coin is flipped $N$ times. I am looking for a formal way to determine how the probability for tossing exactly $N/2$ times "heads" behaves for large $N$.

The probabilty $p$ of getting $x$ times "heads" is

$$ p(x) \enspace = \enspace {N \choose x} \cdot \frac{1}{2^x} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{N-x}} \enspace = \enspace {N \choose x} \cdot \frac{1}{2^N}$$

If now $x \mapsto N/2$, then

$$ p(N/2) \enspace = \enspace {N \choose N/2} \cdot \frac{1}{2^N} \enspace = \enspace {2N \choose N} \frac{1}{2^N}$$

I guess, in the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$ the probability should become $p(N/2) \rightarrow 1$, because if the coin is fair, then I would assume that the more coins there are flipped, the more it converges to its probability of $1/2$. But how do I show this mathematically? However, the limit

$$ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} p(N/2) \enspace = \enspace \infty$$

does not converge. Why is this the case? Where is the error in my thinking?

Comment: "*I guess in the limit the probability should become $p(N/2)\to 1$*"  No, quite the opposite.  It will approach zero.  The more coins there are, the more "*near misses*" there are where we flipped close to but not quite exactly half as heads.

Comment: You switched some of $N's$ with $2N$ but not all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:
$$p(N/2) \enspace = \enspace {N \choose N/2} \cdot \frac{1}{2^N}$$
but then you rewrote it incorrectly. By substituting $k=N/2$, you get:
$$p(k) \enspace = \enspace {2k \choose k} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{2k}}$$

The more coin flips you do, the less likely it becomes to get *exactly* 50% heads. If you flip a million times, getting exactly $500000$ heads is quite unlikely (not very different from getting $499999$ or getting $500001$), and much less likely than getting one head out of two coin flips. The above formula should approach $0$ as $k$ gets large.

Comment: I see. That missing square factor in the (1/2) term did the trick for the limit. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $P\big(\frac{N}{2}\big) = \binom{N}{N/2}\frac{1}{2^{N}}$, not $\binom{2N}{N}\frac{1}{2^{N}}$. This error is why your probability did not converge earlier. Anyways, applying the asymptotic approximation $\binom{2x}{x}\approx \frac{4^{x}}{\sqrt{\pi x}}$:

$P\big(\frac{N}{2}\big)\approx \frac{4^{\frac{N}{2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi N}{2}}}\frac{1}{2^{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}$

Thus, $P\big(\frac{N}{2}\big)\rightarrow 0$ for large values of $N$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you as well for your input regarding the asymptotic approximation. This is most useful.